# Yarn can't authenticate with Github Packages - but npm can

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, github-package-registry

**What do I need to do to configure yarn to authenticate with Github Packages?**

I've got a hello-world npm package that I'm trying to publish privately to github.  I want to be able to use yarn instead of npm, but for some reason yarn can't authenticate with the Github Package service:

```
error Couldn't publish package: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myuser/test-models: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured."
```

NPM doesn't have any trouble publishing though, so I'm assuming it's some difference in the way yarn processes the config info.

**Verbose yarn publish:**

```
$ yarn publish --verbose
yarn publish v1.10.1
verbose 0.257170891 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.npmrc".
verbose 0.257665932 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.npmrc".
verbose 0.258189892 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/.npmrc".
verbose 0.258433341 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/.npmrc".
verbose 0.258899667 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.259174747 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.npmrc".
verbose 0.259487532 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.npmrc".
verbose 0.260003161 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/.npmrc".
verbose 0.260246617 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/.npmrc".
verbose 0.260455656 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/.npmrc".
verbose 0.260965719 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.npmrc".
verbose 0.263449669 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.263757077 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.264027657 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.264629421 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.264905752 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.265187834 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/sites/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.265428211 Checking for configuration file "/Users/myuser/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.265682381 Found configuration file "/Users/myuser/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.26612276 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.268430721 current time: 2020-07-15T16:04:57.727Z
[1/4] Bumping version...
info Current version: 0.0.3
question New version:
info Proceeding with current version: 0.0.3
[2/4] Logging in...
[3/4] Publishing...
verbose 3.449685972 Performing "PUT" request to "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myuser/test-models".
verbose 3.757506429 Request "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myuser/test-models" finished with status code 401.
verbose 3.760342835 Error: Couldn't publish package: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myuser/test-models: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured."
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.10.1/libexec/lib/cli.js:243:66)
    at new MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.10.1/libexec/lib/cli.js:272:123)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.10.1/libexec/lib/cli.js:80723:13
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.10.1/libexec/lib/cli.js:98:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.10.1/libexec/lib/cli.js:111:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
error Couldn't publish package: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myuser/test-models: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured."
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/publish for documentation about this command.
```

**Yarn config:**

```
$ yarn config list
yarn config v1.10.1
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.10.1 npm/? node/v13.11.0 darwin x64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1594760187916
}
info npm config
{
  '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken': '<auth_token1_here>',
  '@myuser:registry': 'https://npm.pkg.github.com',
  '//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken': '<auth_token2_here>',
  python: '/usr/bin/python'
}
✨  Done in 0.11s.
```

**All my config files:**

```
$ cat /Users/myuser/.npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=[my-npm-token]

$ cat /Users/myuser/sites/test-models/.npmrc
@myuser:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=[my-github-token]

$ cat /Users/myuser/.npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=[my-npm-token]

$ cat /Users/myuser/.yarnrc
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


lastUpdateCheck 1594760187916
```

Comment: I appreciate this question, as I'm digging into github packages as well. A couple questions: 1. Have you used `npm login`? 2. What does the successful `npm publish` look like?

Answer (score 1):

For `npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken`, you could try and use the third type of token which is just released yesterday (Oct. 2nd, 2020):

> ### npm automation tokens

> npm is introducing a new setting for access tokens to support publishing to the npm registry from CI/CD workflows.
>
> Previously, you could create an access token with one of two settings: read-only, and publish.
> A publish token allows you to publish packages, like the name implies, but if you have two-factor authentication (2FA) enabled on your account, you'll be prompted for your one-time passcode.
>
> We recommend that people set up 2FA on their account for added security, but requiring a passcode means that all publishing must be done interactively. Many people want to automate their publish step with a CI/CD workflow.
>
> Today, we've added a third option for access tokens: automation. You can create an automation token in your access token settings page.
>
> [image: https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1130014/94804251-6cee9780-03e2-11eb-9380-f18a7b410b9b.png?ssl=1 -- Access token type selection]
>
> Using an automation token will not prompt for a one-time passcode, meaning that you can use it as a secret in your publish workflow. Now you can publish a package directly to the npm registry when you cut a release.
>
> If you're a package maintainer, and you want to require that publishers to your package continue to use two-factor authentication and publish interactively, you can do that in the package settings.
> If you already required 2FA, there's no change to this behavior; automation tokens won't be accepted unless you allow them to be.
>
> If you've been waiting to enable two-factor authentication on your npm account because it prevented you from publishing in an automated workflow, you can now [set up an automation token](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-viewing-access-tokens) and enable 2FA.